# Flutter change icons 2 times

Tags: flutter

I have a very simple question i am changing icon on click by set state.

Like this:

```
  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        isPressed = true;
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      height: Height * 0.01,
      child: isPressed
          ? Icon(Icons.favorite_border)
          : Icon(Icons.favorite),
    ),
  ),
```

What I need is its changing icon fine, but what I need is when I click again its changes again. For example when I click on icon right now its showing Icons.favorite_border but after again click i want to go on Icons.favorite

Comment: isPressed = !isPressed;

Answer (score 1):

Use the opposite value of `isPressed` when setting.

```
isPressed = !isPressed;
```